# SQL Join tables of elements that have two types

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have a table of objects that can have two types:

objects:

```
id | name | type1 | type2 |
-------------------------
1  | bla  |   5   |   7   |
```

and a table of types

types:

```
id | name |
-----------
5  | typ5 |
7  | typ7 |
```

**How could I join them like the following?**

```
object.id | object.name | typename1 | typename2 |
------------------------------------------------
```

I tried the following, but I obtained two rows per object

```
SELECT objects.id,objetcs.name,types.name
from objects
INNER JOIN types
ON objects.type1=types._id OR objects.type2=types._id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two joins:

```
SELECT o.id, o.name, t1.name as name1, t2.name as name2
from objects o LEFT OUTER JOIN
     types t1
     ON o.type1 = t1._id LEFT OUTER JOIN
     types t2
     on o.type2 = t2._id;
```

Comment: good answer. what he's doing is aliasing the table name twice. you can also right it as `types as t1` an `types as t2` if that's clearer to you